# Incrementing variables inside conditional statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, increment, conditional-statements

So, I recently thought I was being really clever (something I've learned is not always a good trait when programing) and tried to refactor something like this:

```
counter++
if (counter > something) {
    doThisCoolThing()
}
```

into something like this

```
if (++counter > something) {
    doThisCoolThing()
}
```

but I was immediately told that I shouldn't do this and had to move the counter incrementing back up a line.

I scoured the internet for information on the subject, and I came up with a few pages on the MDN, the most relevant saying ["The increment operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value. [...] If used prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the value after incrementing."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment), which seems to indicate that incrementing a variable inside a conditional statement would be completely legitimate. The only somewhat related warning I could find was regarding [simple assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#if...else_statement), e.g. `if (x = y)`, but that `if ((x = y))` was okay.

I just wanted to get some other opinions on this. Is it bad practice or is it completely valid?

Thank you

Comment: As this is not a question where there is a correct answer, you should ask your question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Semantically there is no difference, so your program should behave the same way.

Comment: that works the problem is the code is difficult to read. In my opinion, it is not a good practice.

Comment: Who was it that told you you shouldn't do it, a friend, a colleague, a superior, another person on stack overflow?

Comment: @hgoebl It's border-line IMO. Technically there is an answer, or rather a number of answers as to why one is better than the other. I would say it's more bordering on the side of opinionated answers, but depending upon his response to my above question, I _may_ have an actual answer. Plus he's shown a genuine research effort into it.

Comment: There is a factual question here in "is it bad practice?" An answer to that question can reference a few Javascript style guides.

Comment: @JamieBarker Well, in this case the person who told me so was the owner of the repository, so obviously they are correct under these circumstances, but I was wondering in a more general sense if there was something wrong with writing it in the shorter way, e.g. if some popular JS engines parse it differently. From your comments, it seems that it's just a question of readability and a choice for the lead developer to make?

Comment: @ahstro Yes, when there's already a code base there that has been written a certain way, all other party members should aim to code in the same format. This means debugging code can be a lot easier in the long run. Generally there is nothing wrong with writing it that way, maybe not as easy to read what it's doing but that's about it AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You ar right! You can use the brackets for your increment!

```
if((++a)>somthing){
 doSomthing();
}
```

This must help you :)